# Eclipse doesn't compile anymore

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I have Eclipse Oxygene 3.

I worked with Liferay SDK 6.2, tomcat 7.6

I've always compiled Liferay portlets (Liferay->SDK->deploy, Liferay->SDK->war etc etc) but I did some updates to Eclipse libraries (Install new software) and now I can not compile anymore.

I have this error that I can not understand, I have searched around but I have no solutions.

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.setAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Any idea?

Comment: Difficult to say with so little information, but it looks like you are using something that requires at least Eclipse Photon.

Comment: I'd say: Revert the update and then either do them component by component, or download a fully packaged version of the plugins you need. We don't even know which plugins you had installed in the first place - let alone which one is causing the problem. Further more: This is the first time I've heard of Tomcat 7.6...

Comment: How can i revert the update? I tried to install libraries for opencms, after installed them Liferay is not work anymore. I tried to re-install libraries for Liferay but it's not working anymore. Maybe i have to reinstall Eclipse.